# A Question About $dy$ and $dx$ Calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently reading Thompson's Calculus Made Easy. Thompson states that given $y=x^2$ if we add $dx$ to x, and add $dy$ to y, then $y+dy=(x+dx)^2$.

My question though, is how can we assume that $y+dy=(x+dx)^2$? If I set $dy$ to 3, and $dx$ to 1, and set $y$ and $x$ to a constant,  $y+dy$ would not be equal to $(x+dx)^2$ just because $y=x^2$.

So what about $dy$ and $dx$ ensures that $y+dy=(x+dx)^2$?

Comment: You cannot pick arbitrary values for your differentials. They are related by a radio, which we usually see written as $dy/dx$. These values are also generally meant to be infinitesimal.

Comment: What do you mean, "given $y-x^2$"?  Did you mean $y=x^2$?

Comment: @BillWallis But what about that ratio ensures that dy and dx will be equal when plugged into a function?

Comment: @lulu Yes, I did. I corrected it now.

Comment: @EthanChan They are not equal. In your example, you have $dy/dx = 2x$ which gives you the ratio.

Comment: @BillWallis Sorry, I meant that dy = f(dx). Are you saying that dx is a value such that for any value of dx, f(dx)=dy?

Comment: @EthanChan Not quite. Instead I'm claiming that $dy = f'(x) dx$. This follows from the fact that $dy/dx$ and $f'(x)$ are usually considered to be the same thing.

Comment: Nobody said that $dy=f(dx)$.  Think of it in terms of increments.  We define $\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$ which implies $f(x)+\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)$ or $y+\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)$.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry, I don't quite get what that means. Can you try saying it without using delta notation?

Comment: @lulu Perhaps the drawing of a graph would help.

Comment: @BillWallis  Never got the hang of embedding graphs on this site.  I'm writing up the algebra below...feel free to post the graphic version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y$ is a function of $x$. What Thompson is trying to say is that when $x$ is increased by a tiny amount ($\mathrm{d}x$) then $y$ will also increase by a tiny amount ($\mathrm{d}y$). In other words, $\mathrm{d}y$ is the tiny change we cause in $y$ when we make the tiny change $\mathrm{d}x$.

Consider the figure below and assume that $\Delta x$ means the same thing as $\mathrm{d}x$. When we increase $x$ by $\mathrm{d}x$, we move from $A$ to $C$. Hence, the $x$ co-ordinate of $C$ is $x+\mathrm{d}x$.

But by moving to the right from $A$ to $C$, the function (the diagonal black line) has also moved from $A$ to $B$. But where has the function moved to when our $x$ co-ordinate is that of $B$ or $C$?

Since the function is $y=x^2$, we can see that at $B$, $y=(x+\mathrm{d}x)^2$. But our function has also moved up by $\mathrm{d}y$ so we say $y+\mathrm{d}y=(x+\mathrm{d}x)^2$.

In a nutshell, the $\mathrm{d}x$ is *inside* the brackets since we're performing the function on $x$. But the $\mathrm{d}y$ is *outside* the brackets since we're seeing how our $y$ changes when we make the change in $x$.

Does this make sense?

[image]

As pointed out in the comments, $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ aren't really specific numbers, as it's more useful to have them as algebraic variables. We're perfectly entitled to use specific numbers and say that $\underbrace{4}_y+\underbrace{0.42}_{\mathrm{d}y}=(\underbrace{2}_x+\underbrace{0.1}_{\mathrm{d}x})^2$ but keeping the terms as variables is instrumental in progressing to calculus.

Comment: Thank you so much! So dy is the amount x will increase if x is increased by dx?

Comment: @EthanChan Almost! $\mathrm{d}y$ is that amount that $\color{red}{y}$ will change if $x$ is increased by $\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Also, it's a minor point but *"change"* might be a better word than *"increase"* for $y$ as not all functions increase as you move left-to-right.

Comment: Last thing thanks. Let's take a parabola y=x^2, and let's say we take an x value 3. The y value should be 9 right? Then let's take dx=1, so the x value is 4.The y value would then be 16. So dy=7. But then should dy/dx=2(3)=6, since the original value we started with was 3?

Comment: @EthanChan As the other comments have pointed out, it's not common to assign specific values to $\mathrm{d}x$ or $\mathrm{d}y$. But in your example since $\mathrm{d}x=1$ and $\mathrm{d}y=7$, we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac71=7$. As you progress in calculus, you'll find that it's more useful to make $\mathrm{d}x$ smaller and smaller until it's almost $0$.

Comment: The end-goal of finding $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is to find the slope of $y=x^2$. So as we make $\mathrm{d}x$ smaller and smaller, we get a better estimate of what the slope is. If we were looking for the slope at $x=3$, we could make $\mathrm{d}x=0.1$ to get $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{0.61}{0.1}=6.1$. Or  $\mathrm{d}x=0.01$ to get $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{0.601}{0.01}=6.01$. And you can see that as $\mathrm{d}x$ gets really small, $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ gets closer to $6$ (which is the true slope of $y=x^2$ at $x=3$). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

The key issue in differential calculus is "given a function $y=f(x)$, what happens to $y$ as $x$ moves a small amount?".    To write that formally, we pick a small number which we'll call $\Delta x$.  In practice, you could actually choose a value for this or better, a sequence of values decreasing to $0$.  But whatever $\Delta x$ is, we then define $\Delta y$ as $$\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$$  In words, $\Delta y$ is the change in $y$ for a given change in $x$.

Of course that relation can be rewritten as $$f(x)+\Delta y= f(x+\Delta x)\quad \text {or} \quad y+\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)$$

Again, you may think of this as a purely numerical statement.  If $f(x)$ is simple enough you could compute $\Delta y$ explicitly, given an explicit $\Delta x$.

This is what is meant in your text.  They take it a little further in replacing the increments by differentials but I expect they aren't inclined to define the differential in any formal way...all that is intended is to consider the limit as $\Delta x $ tends to $0$.

Example.  $y=x^2$

Then $$y+\Delta y = (x+\Delta x)^2=x^2+2x\Delta x+\Delta x^2\implies \Delta y = 
2x\Delta x+\Delta x^2 $$

We arrange to get $$\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=2x+\Delta x$$  and now we can pass to the limit as $\Delta x\to 0$ to get $$\frac {dy}{dx}=2x$$

So the numerical relations we have defined become the usual derivative in the limit.